Calculate the radius of the circle that is tangent to the two others and to a line tangent to these two circles
Two circles with radii $R$ and $r$ intersect at an angle of $120°$.
A common external tangent $AB$ is drawn ($A$ and $B$ are points of tangency).
Calculate the size of the radius of the circle that is tangent to the first two and tangent to $AB$.
(Answer: $\frac{Rr}{4(\sqrt{R}+\sqrt{r})^2}$)
I tried to make the figure but I don't know if it's correct and I couldn't develop the question.

$O'$ is the center of the smaller circle.
$\triangle IO'O:(r-x)^2+(IO')^2=(r+x)^2\implies IO'^2=r^2+2rx+x^2 -r^2+2rx-x^2 =4rx $
$\triangle JO'P:(R-x)^2+(JO')^2=(R+x)^2\implies JO'^2=R^2+2Rx+x^2 -R^2+2Rx-x^2 =4Rx $

Your diagram is correct and I will refer to it in this answer.
Connect $OP$. By cosine rule we can find that $OP^2=R^2+r^2-Rr.$
WLOG assume $R>r$ and draw a line parallel to $IJ$ through $O$ such that it intersects $PB$ at $Q$. Now considering $\triangle OPQ$, $OP^2=OQ^2+PQ^2\implies OQ^2=OP^2-(R-r)^2=Rr.$
Since you have already found $IO'$ and $JO'$ in terms of $R$ and $r$, you can derive the expression for $x$ using $IJ=OQ=IO'+JO'$.

It's been a while my friend... I appreciate the solution

I have had a problem for some time without resolution.. Can I post to take a look?
Refers to a triangle involving several notable points as Spieker. Nagel. Feuerbach...

Glad to help. Please post that question. I will give it a try.

It's posted...if you can look...

I've seen that question. That's indeed a difficult one. I couldn't find a way in yet. Anyway, I will keep that problem in mind.

Grateful for the attention

I added 2 theorems that might help with the resolution.. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4930301/find-the-sum-of-the-sizes-of-the-segments-formed-by-the-feuerbach-point-and-the
