Find the sum of the sizes of the segments formed by the Feuerbach point and the Nagel point
In an acute-angled triangle, if the sizes of the segments that join the median point with the Spieker point, the Spieker point with the circumcenter and the median point with the circumcenter are $5$,$5$ and $7$m respectively.
Calculate the sum of the sizes of the segments formed by the Feuerbach point and the Nagel point.(ANswer $12,5$m)
I've had this issue for some time now and I can't resolve it.
I apologize but I can't develop it since I can't even make the figure.
I don't know what the "median point" would be. It seems to me that it wouldn't be the center of gravity.
It asks for the sum of the distances from the Feuerbach point. to the point of Nagel.? Is there more than one Feuerbach point?



Comment: I think the author of the question means incenter by the triangle median point, it can not be constructed  with neasures given otherwise. I could not find anything named triangle median.In picture:
O is circumcircle.
H is orthocenter.
$N_1$ is the center of nine point circle.
D, E and F are the mid points of sides AB, AC and BC.
T is Spieker center.
I is in center.
M, G, U and V are Feuerbach points.
N is the Nagel point.
The measures wanted are $NM$ and $NG+Nu+Nv$.
Update: Following facts can be used for solution:
I R, r and $r_n$ are radii of circumcircle, incircle and nine point circle then we have:
$r_n=\frac R2$
cosidering picture:
$r=r_n+\frac{(ZB_1=IT)}2$
$d^2=IO^2=R(R-2r)$ (Euler's theorem)
Using these you can fin R and r and construct the trangle due to given values. This will help to find the required measures.

grateful for the attention

I believe that the median point in Peruvian geometry would be the barycenter and not the incenter –

Hi...I added 2 theorems that might help with the resolution
